# XML Schema error: element "name" not allowed for content model "(name)"

Tags: xml

I'm new to XML and struggling to get my first XML schema to validate the pre-made xml document properly. This may be a fairly basic question, but I can't find a good answer to it and don't understand the problem at all.

Here's my XML document:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <x:presentations xmlns:x="jon:presentations"
                          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                          xs:schemaLocation="jon:presentations presentations.xsd">
      <presentation date="2013-07-31" length="PT30M">
        <topic genre="Music">PianoML</topic>
        <presenters>
          <name title="Mr." id="Y258">
            <first>Elvis</first>
            <middle>A</middle>
            <last>Presley </last>
          </name>
          <name title="Miss" id="X365">
            <first>Lady</first>
            <last>Gaga</last>
          </name>
        </presenters>
      </presentation>
        <presentation date="2013-08-05" length="PT35M">
        <topic genre="Science">AlienML</topic>
        <presenters>
             <name title="Mr." id="Y007">
            <first>Will</first>
            <last>Smith</last>
          </name>
          <name title="Mr." id="Y360">
            <first>Tommy</first>
            <first>Lee</first>
            <last>Jones</last>
          </name>
        </presenters>
      </presentation>
    </x:presentations>
```

And here's my schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        targetNamespace="jon:presentations"
                        xmlns:prs="jon:presentations">
      <xs:element name = "presentations">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name = "presentation">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "topic">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="genre">
                          <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Art"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Science"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Technology"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="presenters">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="name">
                        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"
                                                minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                            <xs:element name="middle" type="xs:string"
                                                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:attribute name="title" use="required">
                              <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Mr."/>
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Mrs."/>
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Ms."/>
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Miss"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                              </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                            <xs:attribute name="id">
                              <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
                                  <xs:pattern value="[X-Y][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                              </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:date">
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:duration">
              </xs:attribute>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

I haven't the faintest clue why, but when I try to validate the xml document, it gives me an error at line 17 saying element "name" is not allowed for content model "(name)"

I need to figure out how to change my schema so this validates properly.

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just missed the minOuccur and maxOccur attributes for the sequences , for the XSD schema to validate the XML - on your sequence you need to mention the minOccur and maxOccur attribute - for Example in your case

Presentation and Name can appear in sequence - so add

```
minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
```

on the sequence of name and sequence of presentation , go through the change and let me know if it was helpful

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                        targetNamespace="jon:presentations"
                        xmlns:prs="jon:presentations">
      <xs:element name = "presentations">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name = "presentation">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name = "topic">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute name="genre">
                          <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="Art"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Science"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="Technology"/>
                            </xs:restriction>
                          </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="presenters">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                      <xs:element name="name">
                        <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                          <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="first" type="xs:string"
                                                minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                            <xs:element name="middle" type="xs:string"
                                                minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
                            <xs:element name="last" type="xs:string"/>
                          </xs:sequence>
                            <xs:attribute name="title" use="required">
                              <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Mr."/>
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Mrs."/>
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Ms."/>
                                  <xs:enumeration value="Miss"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                              </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                            <xs:attribute name="id">
                              <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:ID">
                                  <xs:pattern value="[X-Y][0-9][0-9][0-9]"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                              </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:attribute>
                        </xs:complexType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="date" type="xs:date">
              </xs:attribute>
              <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:duration">
              </xs:attribute>
            </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Comment: Wow, yea that worked and there were no further errors. Thanks!